# Spock order tests by packages

Tags: java, testing, groovy, spock

He,everyone! My tests are running by jenkins from general package. Can I set test package in spock which will be runnning first and if in this package will not passed any of test the other tests should be skipped. I saw examples like this:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;    
@RunWith(Suite.class)    
@Suite.SuiteClasses({TestJunit1.class, TestJunit2.class})    
  public class JunitTestSuite {   
  }
```

But maybe spock has solution where I can use packages instead enum of each classes, because I have many test classes in other many packages.
Also after i used runner

```
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class TestRunner {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(JunitTestSuite.class);    
      for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
        System.out.println(failure.toString());
      }         
      System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
   }
}
```

The main thread doesnt stop. I dont know why.
I want to do something like that:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;    
@RunWith(Suite.class)    
@Suite.SuiteClasses({com.example.test.*.class})    
   public class JunitTestSuiteFirst {   
   }
```

---

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;        
@RunWith(Suite.class)        
@Suite.SuiteClasses({com.example.otherTest.*.class, com.example.otherTests2.*.class})        
   public class JunitTestSuiteFirst {   
    }
```

---

```
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class TestRunner {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(JunitTestSuite.class);    
      for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
         System.out.println(failure.toString());
      }
      if(result.wasSuccessful()){
         JUnitCore.runClasses(JunitTestSuite.class);
      }else {
         System.out.println("Build failed");
      }
   }
}
```

Or maybe exist more simple solution of this task. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything you can work out inside your unit testing framework isn't going to be pretty. This is because unit tests are supposed to be independent from each other, with that mindset there won't be strong support for configuring the order of tests. As such your best bet is to look for your solution in your build tools (Ant, Maven, Gradle, etc).

The following gradle snippet sets up 2 different sets/directories of unit tests. With the command `gradle test integrationTest build` the tests under src/integration will only run if all the tests under src/test pass.

```
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/integration']
        }
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['src/integration']
        }
        resources.srcDir file('src/integration/resources')
    }

    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/test']
        }
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['src/test']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All my test locate in one package. Yes, after some trying . I added turn of starting in gradle file.I added exclude in one task for package and include only needed package in other task. And set dependsOn between this tasks